# How to Unit Test a Class That Has a Static Method Which Gets Information From an External Resource

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

In our application we have a method that calls a static class. This class has a method that gets information from a database.

The Load method is called on the Startup.cs of the application, thus, it only runs once. The rationale behind this approach is since the list of holidays only changes once a year, it doesn't make sense to get this information from the database for every single request made to `GetHolidayNames()`.

```
// Method calling the static class
public class HolidayService()
{
    public List<string> GetHolidayNames()
    {
        var result = Loader.HolidayNames;

        return result;
    }
}

// Static class
public static class Loader
{
    public static List<string> HolidayNames;

    public static void Load(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        HolidayNames = unitOfWork.Holidays.GetHolidayNames();

        return;
    }
}
```

Is it still possible to unit test `GetHolidayNames()` given this scenario?

Comment: Sure it is possible. Just, you need to have additional implementation of your IUnitOfWork interface, which will be some mock class. Then your unit test will instantiate that mock class (using IoC container), so you will not communicate with database. And with this approach you can implement test for `Load` method, and also for `GetHolidayNames` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is still possible to unit test. Given your code snippet I've created a unit test with xUnit and Moq that I believe will allow for the `GetHolidayNames()` to be unit tested. I understand that the assertion at the end isn't probably what you're looking for, but I've added it to complete this example.

```
[Fact]
public void TestHolidayService()
{
    // Use Moq to create a mock of your IUnitOfWork
    var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    
    // Setup the getter which is called on IUnitOfWork (may need to set up more state for .GetHolidayNames())
    mockUnitOfWork.SetupGet(x => x.Holidays).Returns(new Holiday());
    
    // Call the Load method with mocked IUnitOfWork
    Loader.Load(mockUnitOfWork.Object);
    var sut = new HolidayService();

    var result = sut.GetHolidayNames();

    Assert.NotNull(result);
}
```